# Не работает Apache в XAMPP

Tags: windows, wordpress, apache, localhost, xampp

Привет всем! Помогите кто сталкивался: в XAMPP   не работает Apache. Скайп не установлен, порты main & ssl менял на 8080 & 1443 соответственно.

> Problem detected!
> 20:00:24  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 3536!
> 20:00:24  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
> 20:00:24  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
> 20:00:24  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
> 20:00:24  [Apache]  Problem detected!
> 20:00:24  [Apache]  Port 443 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 3536!
> 20:00:24  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
> 20:00:24  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
> 20:00:24  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

Comment: переустанови или поставь другую сборку вроде `open server`

Comment: переустанавливал. ставил wamp , denwer ничего не работает. когда была семерка ставил wamp без всяких проблем, а на десятке не могу

Comment: Нужно выяснить что за приложение мешает вашему Apache. Я так понимаю у вас Windows? Посмотрите в диспетчере задач процесс под этим номером (по умолчанию этот столбец не должен отображаться)

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы узнать, какое приложение прослушивает TCP-порт, необходимо в командной строке выполнить `netstat -abn`

Answer (score -1):

А Вы отключите приложения которые занимаю 80 и 443 порт, это зачастую Skype.

Comment: в вопросе указано, что скайп даже не установлен :)

Comment: @alenkins прочитайте ещё раз внимательно мой ответ, качающийся портов